# what is the max size of the texture iphone can support?

Tags: iphone

1024*1024?
or only 2048*2048 in iPhone3gs and up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As iPhone 3GS has [PowerVR SGX535](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Models) GPU maximum texture size should be 2048x2048. For 3g limit is 1024x1024. You can find those limits in [PLatform notes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) section of "OpenGL ES programming guide".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are [right on the money](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)